# update Google fusiontable using oauth token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables, insert-update

I already have the token and can access my token whose scopes are till fusiontable.
http://www.udayan2k12.com/token.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function() {
     var GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
     var GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "365219651081-7onk7h52kas6cs5m17t1api72ur5tcrh.apps.googleusercontent.com";
     var PLUS_ME_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables";

     var button = document.createElement("button");
     button.innerText = "Authenticate with Google";
     button.onclick = function() {
       var req = {
         "authUrl" : GOOGLE_AUTH_URL,
         "clientId" : GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
         "scopes" : [ PLUS_ME_SCOPE ],
       };
       oauth2.login(req, function(token) {
         alert("Got an OAuth token:\n" + token + "\n"
             + "Token expires in " + oauth2.expiresIn(req) + " ms\n");
             document.getElementById('token').innerHTML = token;
       }, function(error) {
         alert("Error:\n" + error);
       });
     };
     document.body.appendChild(button);

     var clearTokens = document.createElement("button");
     clearTokens.innerText = "Clear all tokens";
     clearTokens.onclick = oauth2.clearAllTokens;
     document.body.appendChild(clearTokens);
   })();
  </script>
```

But the problem is that i am unable to use that token to update the fusion table.
I want to update it specifically by using JavaScript.

can some one provide me the code to use this token to update fusiontable using the fusion table sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know most of you are suffering for google auth and inserting and updating fusion table.
I am providing the entire code how to use the gauth lib to insert in a simple manner

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Authorization Request</title>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function auth() {
        var config = {
          'client_id': '365219651081-7onk7h52kas6cs5m17t1api72ur5tcrh.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'
        };
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
          console.log('login complete');
          console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
        });
      }
      function insert_row(){
            alert("insert called");
            gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyA0FVy-lEr_MPGk1p_lHSrxGZDcxy6wH4o');

            var query = "INSERT INTO 1T_qE-o-EtX24VZASFDn6p3mMoPcWQ_GyErJpPIc(Name, Age) VALUES ('Trial', 100)";

            gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function(){
                gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({sql:query}).execute(function(response){console.log(response);});
            });

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button onclick="insert_row();">Insert Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [JavaScript Google API client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client), then it is very easy to make authenticated requests to a Google API (see [their "Samples" page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Samples)):

```js
gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR API KEY');
var query = "INSERT INTO tableId (id, name) VALUES (1, 'test')";
gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function(){
            gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({sql:query}).execute(function(response){console.log(response);});
        });
```