# Fusion table update

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I used the sample code given here and it worked.

[update Google fusiontable using oauth token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626107/update-google-fusiontable-using-oauth-token)

Next day it doesn't. When I now click Authorize the oauth2 screen popups up then disappears immediately and my sql update is not actioned.

What went wrong?

Thanks for your help and supplying the code snippet.

Comment: You might want to include a link to the original question or the code that was given to you, otherwise this will get closed very quickly for not having much to work on.

Comment: thanks for the tip. it's my first question here.

Comment: Which code did you use? It's best to include it directly in your question. Did you use the [Google API JavaScript client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/)?